# How to omit some results but not all from a query

Tags: mysql, sql-like, notin

Say I have a table with a field called foo. Foo is a character field.
I want to return all records where foo is:

1. Not in ('ad','ca','qw')
2. Not like '9%' unless it is '96321'

Here is what I have but I am tripping up on how to get '96321'

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    mtable
WHERE
    foo NOT IN ('ad' , 'ca', 'qw')
        AND foo NOT LIKE '9%';
```

Comment: unless it is '96321' or they may be other numbers starts with 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OR condition, query will be as per below:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    mtable
WHERE
    foo NOT IN ('ad' , 'ca', 'qw')
        AND (foo NOT LIKE '9%' OR foo='96321');
```

Comment: @Zafar - Of course, thank you. I was just having a brain lapse.